# Python script to convert .pcl to .pdf

Tags: ghostscript, pcl

I see some programs that are trying to accomplish the .pcl to .pdf conversion and doing it successfully, but i didn't manage to find a simple solution that can run on any machine, independently, often there is much configuration etc.

Is there a quick solution for the .pcl to .pdf conversion, like a python package, or a script that can run on Linux, except from Ghostscript?